# Compilation failure when using a base class reference as a predicate

Tags: c++11

```
class baseFunctor{
  virtual ~baseFunctor() {}
  virtual bool operator()(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) = 0;
};
class derivedFunctor : public baseFunctor{
  bool operator()(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) override { /*implementation*/ }
};
```

Inside another unrelated method, I have :

```
baseFunctor* functor = new derivedFunctor();
std::vector<A> vectorA;
```

My intention is to use this functor as a compare function like this:

```
std::make_heap(vectorA.begin(),vectorA.end(),*functor);
```

However, I get the following error:

> C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'void
>   std::make_heap(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)'

What is the proper way to use my pointer to functor in that situation?

Comment: Why is your functor taking lvalue references to non-const? It should be `bool operator()(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)`. Also, why are you using `new` to create the functor? If you really need to create it on the heap, go with `std::make_unique<>`...

Comment: @AndyProwl Element order in vectorA drives the behaviour in my case. I want others to change the behaviour by implementing their  functors. How else could I achieve my goal? I completly agrre with const usage.

Comment: If you really need run-time polymorphism then yes, you can allocate the functor on the heap and use inheritance, but naked `new` and owning raw pointers in general are discouraged in modern C++. `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` are the tools you should reach for in this case. Anyway even assuming you need run-time polymorphism (i.e. which comparison algorithm to be used is only known at run-time, so templates are not a viable option) consider whether the inheritance-based solution is really necessary: `std::function` is often simpler and more flexible (you may want to read about it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function objects are passed by value in standard algorithms. This means that the `derivedFunctor` object will be passed by value as a `baseFunctor`. Since `baseFunctor` is an abstract class that code cannot compile. (If it was not an abstract class the code would compile, but probably misbehave because of the object slicing problem.)

In order to make this work, you can use something like `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
std::make_heap(vectorA.begin(),vectorA.end(),std::ref(*functor));
```

This works because the reference wrapper object avoids copying the functor and keeps a reference instead; and because it is directly callable and simply forwards arguments to the object reference.